¿Por qué el diseño se ve bien pero al ejecutar la app no se ve de la misma manera en android studio?
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Android y me gustaría que se ajustara correctamente a diferentes tamaños de pantalla de dispositivos móviles. He investigado un poco y he encontrado que ConstraintLayout es una buena opción para hacer que las vistas se ajusten dinámicamente a diferentes tamaños de pantalla.
Sin embargo, estoy teniendo dificultades para comprender cómo puedo lograr esto de manera efectiva. ¿Alguien podría proporcionarme orientación sobre cómo utilizar ConstraintLayout para lograr un diseño adaptable que se vea bien en una variedad de dispositivos, desde teléfonos pequeños hasta tabletas grandes?, aquí abajo dejaré imágenes de la parte de diseño en android studio y la imágen de la app ejecutada en mi dispositivo físico.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is a title of my app"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                android:background="@color/green">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Introduccion"
                    android:textSize="28sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



Lo que quiero es que la aplicación, se ajuste a cada pantalla de los dispositivos móviles, quiero hacer una app relativa, pero entiendo que se puede hacer con constrain Layout.

Yo lo veo bien en ambos casos, a que te refieres exactamente?

En la parte del text view del título tengo que bajarle el tamaño en android studio para que se vea bien en el dispositivo físico, y en los demás textview se ven muy grande en el dispositivo físico en comparación con android studio
